# How to remove vertical scrolling created by open dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, dropdown, react-bootstrap

It is just basic example how the vertical scroll is appearing despite of `overflow-y:visible` property.I have a table where i want to have horizontal scrolling in case of large data set.Horizontal scrolling should by dynamic so i set `overflow-x:auto` but this spoils behaviour of opening a dropdown menu which creates vertical scroll.

What is wrong?

Thank you in advance.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  
  render(){
  
    return (
      <ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton
        title='test'
        id='1'
      >
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="3" active>
          Active Item
        </ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem divider />
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
      </ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton>
    )
  
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```css
#container {

  height:50px;
  overflow-y:visible;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to create custom `Dropdown` component which render its menu in [Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) outside of the scope of the element where you dont want to display scrolls.You can set the menu to `position:absolute` and set its absolute position based on `Dropdown` position.

You can get `Dropdown` position using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of you `overflow-x` value, if you remove it and set `overflow: hidden;` it works fine :

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  
  render(){
  
    return (
      <ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton
        title='test'
        id='1'
      >
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="3" active>
          Active Item
        </ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem divider />
        <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
      </ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton>
    )
  
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```css
#container {

  height:50px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as i wrote i want to have dynamic horizontal scroll.How can i manage it?

Comment: Maybe you could try to make the container's parent scrollable

Comment: Have a set a height for the box then have overflow-y: auto.

Comment: @SimonHyll Can not make it work,if you have solution for this problem,please provide some sort of fiddle, thanks.Height of the container is also dynamic,its just a table.

Comment: Use max-height. Im on vacation in spain so i dont have a computer to make a fiddle for you, writing this on my phone.